# Embedded System: which OS should I use?

Tags: android, embedded-linux, embedded

I am planning to build my embedded system for processing the sound of my guitar, like a pod, with input and output and so on and a system running with a program with presets, options etc in a small lcd screen should be multitouch for navigation.

Now I am at the very beginning and dont know where to start and what system I should use.

It should support the features I wrote above (like multitouch) and should be free.

Embedded Linux,
or 
Android 
or what?

Comment: What is your hardware platform?  You need to know that first.

Comment: i want to have the features so the hardware platform would be the next step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using off the shelf effects modules with some sort of interface to an embedded system or are you planning on doing the effects in your program as well?  I assume the latter in this response, please clarify if I have misunderstood the nature of the project:

Do your system engineering...

You are going to need to deal with the analog of the inputs and outputs.  Even digital inputs and outputs are analog in some respects to keep the signals clean.  Even optical is going to be analog between the optical interface and the processors interface.

(I know this is long, keep reading it will converge on the answer to your question)

You will have some sort of hardware to software data in interface, ideally if you choose to support different interfaces you will ideally want to normalize the data into a common form and datarate so that the effects processing only has to deal with it one way.  (avoiding a bunch of if-then-elses in the code, if bitrate is this then, else if bitrate is this then, else...if bitrate is this and data is unipolar then, else if bitrate is this and data is bipolar then, else...).

The guts of the effects processing is as complicated as you want to make it, one effect at a time or multiple?  For each effect define the parameters you are going to allow to be adjusted (I would start with the minimum number which might be none, then add parameters later once it is all working).  These parameters are going to need to be global in some for or fashion so that the user interface can get at them and modify them for the effects processing.

the output, same as the input, a lot of analog work, convert from the normalized data stream into whatever the interface wants or needs or you defined it to be.

then there is the user interface...the easy part.

...

The guts of the software for the effects processing can be system independent code, and is probably more comfortable being developed and tested on a desktop/laptop than on the target system, bearing in mind the code should be written system and operating system independent as well as being written embeddable (avoid floating point, divides, lots of local variables, etc).

Sometimes if not often in an enclosed system with some sort of user interface on the same black box, knobs or buttons a screen of some sort, touch screens, etc.  One system may manage the user interface the other performs the task and there is a connection between.  not always but it is a nice clean design, and allows, for example a product designed yesterday with buttons and knobs and say a two line lcd panel, to be modernized to a touch screen, at a fraction of the effort, and tomorrow sometime there may be some fiber that plugs directly into a socket in the back of your head, who knows.

Another reason to separate the processing tasks is so that it is easier to insure that the effects processor will never get bogged down by user interface stuff. you dont want to be turning a virtual knob on your touchscreen and the graphics load to draw the picture causes your audio to get garbled or turn to a nasty whine.  Basically the effects processor is real-time critical.  you dont want to pick the string on the guitar, and have the sound come out of the amp three seconds later because the processor is also drawing an animated background on your touch screen panel.  That processing needs to be tight and fast and deterministic, every if-then-else in the code has to be accounted for and balanced.  If you allow for multiple effects in parallel your processor needs to be able to have the bandwidth to process all of the effects without a noticeable delay, otherwise if only one effect at a time then the processor needs to be chosen to handle the one effect with the worst computation effort.  The worst that could happen is that the input to output latency varies because of something the gui processing is doing, causing the music to sound horrible.

So you can work the effects processor with its user interface being, for example, a serial interface and a protocol across that interface (which you define) for selecting effects and changing parameters.  You can get the effects processor up and working and tested using your desktop and/or laptop connected through the serial interface with some adhoc code being used to change parameters, perhaps a command line program.

Now is where it becomes interesting.  You can get an off the shelf embedded linux system for example or embedded android or whatever, write your app that uses the serial protocol, if need be glue, bolt, tape, mold, etc this user interface system on top of around, next to the effects processor module.  Note that you could have all of the platforms suggested, an android version, a linux (without android) version, a mac version, a windows version, a dos version, a qnx version, an amiga version, you name it.  You can try 100 different user interface variations on the same OS, maybe I want the knobs to be sliders, or up/down push buttons, or a dial looking thing that I use a two finger touch to rotate, or some other multi-touch gesture.

And it gets better, instead of or in addition to serial you could use a bluetooth module.  Your user interface could be an iPhone app, or android phone app, or laptop linux or windows app. or your desktop computer, etc.  All of which are (relatively) easy platforms for writing graphical user interfaces for selecting things.

Another approach of course could be ethernet, in particular wireless ethernet then your user interface could be a web page and the bulk of your user interface work has already been done by the firefox or chrome or other team.  (wireless ethernet or bluetoot or zigbee or other allows the effects processor to be somewhere convenient and doesnt have to be within arms/foot reach of you).

...

Do your system engineering.  Break the problem into a few big modules, define the interfaces between the modules and then worry about the system engineering if necessary inside those modules until you get to easily digestable bites.  The better the system engineering and the better defined the interfaces between modules the easier the project will be to implement.

...

I would also investigate the xcore processors at xmos, they have a very nice simulator with vcd waveform output that you can also use to accurately profile your effects processing.  Personally I would have a very tough time not choosing this platform for this project.

You should also investigate the omap from ti, this is what is on a beagleboard.  You get a nice arm that already has linux and other things ported and running on it, but you also get a dsp block, that dsp block could do your effects processing and likely in a way that the two dont interfere.  You lose the ability to separate your user interface processor and effects processor physically, but gain elsewhere, and can probably use a beagleboard off the shelf to develop a prototype (using analog audio in and out).  I actually liked the hawkboard better (with the hawkboard you get a usable system out of the box, with the beagleboard you spend another beagleboards worth of money for stuff that should have been on the board), but last I saw they had an instability flaw with the pcb design.

I am not up on the specs but the tegra (a number of upcoming phones are or will be tegra based), like the omap, should give some parallel processing with a lean toward audio/video as well as gui.  You only need the audio and gui (the easier two of the three).  I think there is a development platform for sale that has a touchscreen on it and popular embedded OSes.

If you are trying to save money buy making one of these things yourself.  Stop now and go to the store and buy one.  The homebrew one will cost a lot more, even if all the design stuff is free.  The hardware and melted down guitars and guitar amps are not.  I speak from experience, many times I have spent many thousands of dollars on a homebrew projects to avoid buying some off the shelf $300 item.  I learned an awful lot, and personally the building of the thing is more fun than the using it, I normally shelve it once it is finally working. YMMV

If I have misunderstood your question, please let me know and I will edit/remove/replace all of it with a different (short) answer.

Comment: well, thanks for this great answer. but now i have to choose one platform. it would be great if it has all the wished features and also bluetooth and wlan and touchscreen and so on, so you can control it with a laptop or smartphone, has to be powerful and flexible but not too expensive and easy to develop. saw some embedded systems with very fast intel i3, i5 and i7 processors, but i have no idea, what is better. a full embedded system on an mini itx with the newest processors, als a full pc, or a board like you said (beagleboard, xmos ...

Comment: do you know where you saw the developement platform for tegra?

Comment: here are some http://developer.nvidia.com/tegra-development-kits but these are not the ones I remember seeing though, I have a picture in my head of a board and the right side is covered by an lcd panel with a windows logo of some sort on it, thought it was tegra will keep looking.

Comment: Sounds like what you need to do is start with a sound card and a desktop system, get your thing up and running (linux, andriod, whatever).  then figure out how much processing power you are using/needing and buy a mini computer, maybe an atom based thing or something like that (ahh, well you need/want a multi-touch display dont you, hmmm).  earthlcd has the ezlcd panels, I used the early one, single touch and a bit small.  You might find something there if you buy the components separately.  sparkfun is always a good place for similar things.

Comment: great, will take a look on this =)

Answer (score 1):

In facts it depends on what kind of hardware you want to run and interface (as a consequence how much you will work at driver level... or not).
The problem with android remains the same than with a bare linux. Could even be worse if there is no framework-level library (Java) since you will have to manage C part (with JNI) and the Java part.

Work the specs... then you will choose wisely...

**Reminder: android is linux-based.**

Comment: well, should be as simple as possible but as powerful as possible too. you know the pods for guitars? i want to create my own ones, that i also can chain them, configure the presets and also have an input and output for recording and so on.

Comment: If I understand, you would like to implement digital effects (reverb, phazer, distro) and chain them?

Comment: sort of this, write my own effect pods with qt (c++) and run them on the hardware

Comment: Qt is a great framework but the last time I tried to use Qt Embedded, it was not simple (windows mobile on a ruggedized mobile handheld device). If you eventually choose android, you may find http://sourceforge.net/p/necessitas/home/necessitas/ usefull ;)

Comment: My two cents: your functional specs will certainly yield you to conclude you do not need accelerometer or GPS… Thus that it can be difficult to find an adapted android device out-of-the-box ⇒ then go for a bare linux on a whatever you will find architecture. 1. Specs. 2. Hardware, 3. Software (hw support, android, Qt and co.).

Comment: i want to use qt for linux and not windows mobile (no windows!)

Comment: Can you suggest a board or embedded system dealer with some good embedded systems or boards?

Comment: You cannot assert "I want to use Qt for linux" and "Embedded Linux, or Android or what?"

Comment: Hm, right now im totally confused. Which os and platform should i use? Khronos on Android looks great but Linux ? Dont know oO

Answer (score 0):

Go for Android:

- With any other embedded OS you will have too much of an integration work to deal with.
- You can start by buying off-the-shelf hardware (Galaxy Tab, HTC phone, etc) to start your development and reach a prototype fast

Comment: do you know some dealers where i get the right hardware platform for my own device with android? maybe where i can choose the components i need and start with android on that hardware?